# .net RSA sign data error with PSS padding

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography, sign, rsacryptoserviceprovider

I have a question re. the use of Crypto in .net as follows. I have a .pem file which I am able to parse to a private key and would like to sign some data bytes. The code I'm using is below:

```
byte[] pemkey = Convert.FromBase64String(privateKeyString);

RSACryptoServiceProvider RSA = DecodeRSAPrivateKey(pemkey);//function to parse .pem file

byte[] fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\...");

byte[] signature = RSA.SignData(fileBytes, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256, RSASignaturePadding.Pss);
```

When running this, at the last statement (RSA.SignData), I've got an exception CryptographicException is not handled: **Specified padding mode is not valid for this algorithm.**

I'm not sure what is missing from my code as my search on Google did not return much result.

Any help is appreciated. Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have never seen PSS padding working with `RSACryptoServiceProvider` but I have seen it working fine with `RSACng`. You can try it quickly with following modification of your code:

```
byte[] pemkey = Convert.FromBase64String(privateKeyString);

RSACryptoServiceProvider RSA = DecodeRSAPrivateKey(pemkey);//function to parse .pem file

RSAParameters rsaParams = RSA.ExportParameters(true);
RSACng RSACng = new RSACng();
RSACng.ImportParameters(rsaParams);

byte[] fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\...");

byte[] signature = RSACng.SignData(fileBytes, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256, RSASignaturePadding.Pss);
```

Comment: Correct, RSACryptoServiceProvider doesn't (and won't ever) support PSS.  https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/Documentation/architecture/cross-platform-cryptography.md#rsa

Comment: awesome, it works. MSDN didn't mention anything about not being able to use PSS with RSACryptoServiceProvider. Thanks guys