# Signing XML return invalid signature on api gate and false signaturecheck

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography

I have a problem with signing a XML file with X509 xades certificate. The APi return me invalid signature error and the SignatureCheck() is false.

I did create a SSL cert to sign files yet do the OID order matter? Like I need the OID 2.5.5.97 but it's as first on the row.

The signed and verified XML isn't as different from mine. The largest difference is because of original JAVA gate that have prefixes on signature(:ds). In documentation it's required the transform "http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116 - not(ancestor-or-self::ds:Signature)" yet with the :ds prefix I can't make it run and adding it after the signature would make it false anyway. Similar with SignatureValue Id that I can't create in .net.

Any thoughs about it? SPend a lot of time but I cant figure out what to do since the error don't really says me what to check anymore. I'm using a Overriden XadesSignedXML().

```
    private const string SignatureId = "-72773545-b03c-49fe-98ed-477a2f199934";
    private const string SignaturePropertiesId = "#SignedProps-72773545-b03c-49fe-98ed-477a2f199934";


    private static XmlElement SignXMLDocument(string xml, X509Certificate2 certificate, string signedXMLPath)
    {

        string XPathString = "not(ancestor-or-self::Signature)";

        var xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDocument.PreserveWhitespace = true;
        xmlDocument.Load(xml);

        var signedXml = new XadesSignedXml(xmlDocument);
        signedXml.Signature.Id = "Signature" + SignatureId;
        signedXml.SigningKey = certificate.PrivateKey;
        signedXml.SignedInfo.SignatureMethod = "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256";
        signedXml.SignedInfo.CanonicalizationMethod = "http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#";
        //signedXml.SignatureValue. = "SignatureValue" + SignatureId;
        
        var signatureReference = new Reference { Uri = "", };
        XmlDsigXPathTransform XPathTransform = CreateXPathTransform(XPathString);
        signatureReference.DigestMethod = "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256";
        signatureReference.AddTransform(XPathTransform);
        signedXml.AddReference(signatureReference);
        
        var signatureReference2 = new Reference { Uri = "", };
        signatureReference2.AddTransform(new XmlDsigExcC14NTransform());
        //signatureReference2.Uri = SignaturePropertiesId;
        signatureReference2.Type = "http://uri.etsi.org/01903#SignedProperties";
        signatureReference2.DigestMethod = "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256";
        signedXml.AddReference(signatureReference2);
        
        var keyInfo = new KeyInfo();
        keyInfo.AddClause(new KeyInfoX509Data(certificate));
        signedXml.KeyInfo = keyInfo;
        AddXAdESProperties(xmlDocument, signedXml, certificate);
        signedXml.ComputeSignature();
        
        // Add prefix "ds:" to signature
        XmlElement signature = signedXml.GetXml();
        xmlDocument.DocumentElement.AppendChild(xmlDocument.ImportNode(signature, true));
        signedXml.CheckSignature();


        xmlDocument.Save(signedXMLPath);
        return signedXml.GetXml();
    }






public class XadesSignedXml : SignedXml
    {
        #region Public fields
        public const string XmlDsigSignatureProperties = "http://uri.etsi.org/01903#SignedProperties";
        public const string XadesProofOfApproval = "http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.2.2#ProofOfApproval";
        public const string XadesPrefix = "xades";
        public const string XadesNamespaceUrl = "http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.3.2#";
        public XmlElement PropertiesNode { get; set; }
        #endregion Public fields

        #region Private fields
        private readonly List<DataObject> _dataObjects = new List<DataObject>();
        #endregion Private fields

        #region Constructor
        public XadesSignedXml(XmlDocument document) : base(document) { }
        #endregion Constructor

        #region SignedXml
        public override XmlElement GetIdElement(XmlDocument document, string idValue)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(idValue)) return null;

            XmlElement xmlElement = base.GetIdElement(document, idValue);
            if (xmlElement != null) return xmlElement;


            foreach (DataObject dataObject in _dataObjects)
            {
                XmlElement nodeWithSameId = findNodeWithAttributeValueIn(dataObject.Data, "Id", idValue);
                if (nodeWithSameId != null)
                    return nodeWithSameId;
            }
            if (KeyInfo != null)
            {
                XmlElement nodeWithSameId = findNodeWithAttributeValueIn(KeyInfo.GetXml().SelectNodes("."), "Id", idValue);
                if (nodeWithSameId != null)
                    return nodeWithSameId;
            }
            return null;
        }
        public XmlElement findNodeWithAttributeValueIn(XmlNodeList nodeList, string attributeName, string value)
        {
            if (nodeList.Count == 0) return null;
            foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList)
            {
                XmlElement nodeWithSameId = findNodeWithAttributeValueIn(node, attributeName, value);
                if (nodeWithSameId != null) return nodeWithSameId;
            }
            return null;
        }

        private XmlElement findNodeWithAttributeValueIn(XmlNode node, string attributeName, string value)
        {
            string attributeValueInNode = getAttributeValueInNodeOrNull(node, attributeName);
            if ((attributeValueInNode != null) && (attributeValueInNode.Equals(value))) return (XmlElement)node;
            return findNodeWithAttributeValueIn(node.ChildNodes, attributeName, value);
        }

        private string getAttributeValueInNodeOrNull(XmlNode node, string attributeName)
        {
            if (node.Attributes != null)
            {
                XmlAttribute attribute = node.Attributes[attributeName];
                if (attribute != null) return attribute.Value;
            }
            return null;
        }

        public new void AddObject(DataObject dataObject)
        {
            base.AddObject(dataObject);
            _dataObjects.Add(dataObject);
        }
        #endregion SignedXml
    }

private static void AddXAdESProperties(XmlDocument document, XadesSignedXml xadesSignedXml, X509Certificate2 signingCertificate)
    {

        // <Object>
        var objectNode = document.CreateElement("Object", SignedXml.XmlDsigNamespaceUrl);
        XmlAttribute attr = document.CreateAttribute("Id");
        attr.Value = "Signature" + SignatureId;
        document.DocumentElement.SetAttributeNode(attr);
       // objectNode.SetAttribute("Id", $"#QualifyingInfos{SignatureId}");

        // <Object><QualifyingProperties>
        var qualifyingPropertiesNode = document.CreateElement(XadesSignedXml.XadesPrefix, "QualifyingProperties", XadesSignedXml.XadesNamespaceUrl);
        qualifyingPropertiesNode.SetAttribute("Id", $"QualifyingProps{SignatureId}");
        qualifyingPropertiesNode.SetAttribute("Target", $"#Target{SignatureId}");
        objectNode.AppendChild(qualifyingPropertiesNode);

        // <Object><QualifyingProperties><SignedProperties>
        var signedPropertiesNode = document.CreateElement(XadesSignedXml.XadesPrefix, "SignedProperties", XadesSignedXml.XadesNamespaceUrl);
        signedPropertiesNode.SetAttribute("Id", $"SignedProps{SignatureId}");
        qualifyingPropertiesNode.AppendChild(signedPropertiesNode);

        // <Object><QualifyingProperties><SignedProperties><SignedSignatureProperties>
        var signedSignaturePropertiesNode = document.CreateElement(XadesSignedXml.XadesPrefix, "SignedSignatureProperties", XadesSignedXml.XadesNamespaceUrl);
        signedPropertiesNode.AppendChild(signedSignaturePropertiesNode);

        // <Object><QualifyingProperties><SignedProperties><SignedSignatureProperties> </SigningTime>
        var signingTime = document.CreateElement(XadesSignedXml.XadesPrefix, "SigningTime", XadesSignedXml.XadesNamespaceUrl);
        signingTime.InnerText = $"{DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("s")}Z";
        signedSignaturePropertiesNode.AppendChild(signingTime);

        // <Object><QualifyingProperties><SignedProperties><SignedSignatureProperties><SigningCertificate>
        var signingCertificateNode = document.CreateElement(XadesSignedXml.XadesPrefix, "SigningCertificate", XadesSignedXml.XadesNamespaceUrl);
        signedSignaturePropertiesNode.AppendChild(signingCertificateNode);

        // <Object><QualifyingProperties><SignedProperties><SignedSignatureProperties><SigningCertificate><Cert>
        var certNode = document.CreateElement(XadesSignedXml.XadesPrefix, "Cert", XadesSignedXml.XadesNamespaceUrl);
        signingCertificateNode.AppendChild(certNode);

        // <Object><QualifyingProperties><SignedProperties><SignedSignatureProperties><SigningCertificate><Cert><CertDigest>
        var certDigestNode = document.CreateElement(XadesSignedXml.XadesPrefix, "CertDigest", XadesSignedXml.XadesNamespaceUrl);
        certNode.AppendChild(certDigestNode);

        // <Object><QualifyingProperties><SignedProperties><SignedSignatureProperties><SigningCertificate><Cert><CertDigest> </DigestMethod>
        var digestMethod = document.CreateElement("DigestMethod", SignedXml.XmlDsigNamespaceUrl);
        var digestMethodAlgorithmAtribute = document.CreateAttribute("Algorithm");
        digestMethodAlgorithmAtribute.InnerText = "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256";
        digestMethod.Attributes.Append(digestMethodAlgorithmAtribute);
        certDigestNode.AppendChild(digestMethod);

        // <Object><QualifyingProperties><SignedProperties><SignedSignatureProperties><SigningCertificate><Cert><CertDigest> </DigestMethod>
        var digestValue = document.CreateElement("DigestValue", SignedXml.XmlDsigNamespaceUrl);
        digestValue.InnerText = Convert.ToBase64String(signingCertificate.GetCertHash());
        certDigestNode.AppendChild(digestValue);

        // <Object><QualifyingProperties><SignedProperties><SignedSignatureProperties><SigningCertificate><Cert><IssuerSerial>
        var issuerSerialNode = document.CreateElement(XadesSignedXml.XadesPrefix, "IssuerSerial", XadesSignedXml.XadesNamespaceUrl);
        certNode.AppendChild(issuerSerialNode);

        // <Object><QualifyingProperties><SignedProperties><SignedSignatureProperties><SigningCertificate><Cert><IssuerSerial> </X509IssuerName>
        var x509IssuerName = document.CreateElement("X509IssuerName", SignedXml.XmlDsigNamespaceUrl);
        x509IssuerName.InnerText = signingCertificate.Issuer;
        issuerSerialNode.AppendChild(x509IssuerName);

        // <Object><QualifyingProperties><SignedProperties><SignedSignatureProperties><SigningCertificate><Cert><IssuerSerial> </X509SerialNumber>
        var x509SerialNumber = document.CreateElement("X509SerialNumber", SignedXml.XmlDsigNamespaceUrl);
        x509SerialNumber.InnerText = ToDecimalString(signingCertificate.SerialNumber);
        issuerSerialNode.AppendChild(x509SerialNumber);

        var dataObject = new DataObject();
        dataObject.Data = qualifyingPropertiesNode.SelectNodes(".");
        xadesSignedXml.AddObject(dataObject);
    }

    private static string ToDecimalString(string serialNumber)
    {
        BigInteger bi;

        if (BigInteger.TryParse(serialNumber, NumberStyles.HexNumber, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out bi))
        {
            return bi.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        }
        else
        {
            return serialNumber;
        }
    }



XML output



-<Signature Id="Signature-72773545-b03c-49fe-98ed-477a2f199934" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
-<SignedInfo>
<CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
<SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"/>
-<Reference URI="">
-<Transforms>
-<Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116">
 <XPath>not(ancestor-or-self::Signature)</XPath>
</Transform>
</Transforms>
<DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
<DigestValue>SDYp5ETBmCIef4sWHqyIFYdE5cx2d2OkysrSaOAjIis=</DigestValue>
</Reference>
-<Reference URI="" Type="http://uri.etsi.org/01903#SignedProperties">
-<Transforms>
<Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
</Transforms>
<DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
<DigestValue>REcwU+gablenV+bEsnzWgvrkthDMvbku2wL49GKLsDU=</DigestValue>
</Reference>
</SignedInfo>
 <SignatureValue>GKixR6/kwjMZ2YvY7ENFejW7lLHZtm7EUMxB3gwCRM82yljLe3POky08rFVa7xk/n1FS9NQhReTQkxDz2DfsB0f+hryvln93phmBp9z+u2vWX5RPKFQaaeBnvA8f4hzD9dzE5j+XE5SvJSlhY31ywb5uPobzoKBV2sw+wG3bXMGMdRwic0bAKVXfYlAY5sA3lzXL9IwOKNWJbb9EJvOg/Mvywymni86pRdr6SxReW9l5nWlCiIdQUIM4B7HsghaovL9/ertqEZQ50XM1T5fMfOnw6XBiKP9pEnpklMjcvbZwVscdfWOhbRuUCvyNm/pwJEarTQNB8fKS/SQF4AR2fQ==</SignatureValue>
 -<KeyInfo>
 -<X509Data <X509Certificate>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</X509Certificate>
 </X509Data>
 </KeyInfo>
 -<Object>
 -<xades:QualifyingProperties Id="QualifyingProps-72773545-b03c-49fe-98ed-477a2f199934" xmlns:xades="http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.3.2#" Target="#Target-72773545-b03c-49fe-98ed-477a2f199934">
-<xades:SignedProperties Id="SignedProps-72773545-b03c-49fe-98ed-477a2f199934">
-<xades:SignedSignatureProperties>
 <xades:SigningTime>2022-05-25T10:23:22Z</xades:SigningTime>
-<xades:SigningCertificate>
-<xades:Cert>
-<xades:CertDigest>
 <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
 <DigestValue>0s2aVTeCNbnIYs5tYawTcnSnTUs=</DigestValue>
</xades:CertDigest>
-<xades:IssuerSerial>
<X509IssuerName>OID.2.5.4.97=5035741844, CN=enablebanking.com, C=FI, L=Espoo, O=Enable Banking Oy</X509IssuerName>
<X509SerialNumber>617047229468459973113617196860274611066779525829</X509SerialNumber>
</xaes:IssuerSerial>
</xades:Cert>
</xades:SigningCertificate>
</xades:SignedSignatureProperties>
</xades:SignedProperties>
 </xades:QualifyingProperties>
</Object>
</Signature>
```

My previous question.
[How to add properly xml transformations to sign file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72274298/how-to-add-properly-xml-transformations-to-sign-file)

Comment: The padding default parameters for encryption are different in c# and java.  Does encryption/decryption (checking signature) work in c#, but not in java?

Comment: I can't validate the signature in both c# with signedxml and java using their swagger tool.

Comment: Specify padding like this : byte[] signature = RSA.SignData(fileBytes, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256, RSASignaturePadding.Pss);  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45696437/net-rsa-sign-data-error-with-pss-padding?force_isolation=true  Try different padding modes to see which is compatible with swagger.

Comment: I'm not sure how to add this padding to my code here. Anyway in documentation it states that for my RSA is PKCS#1 padding  allowed.

Answer (score 2):

```
-<Reference URI="" Type="http://uri.etsi.org/01903#SignedProperties">
-<Transforms>
<Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
</Transforms>
<DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
<DigestValue>REcwU+gablenV+bEsnzWgvrkthDMvbku2wL49GKLsDU=</DigestValue>
</Reference>
```

The problem here is more likely the reference of

```
Type="http://uri.etsi.org/01903#SignedProperties"
```

…as it refers the enveloping content instead of the `SignedProperties` element by its `Id`. I.e., the reference should look like:

```
-<Reference URI="#SignedProps-72773545-b03c-49fe-98ed-477a2f199934" Type="http://uri.etsi.org/01903#SignedProperties">
-<Transforms>
<Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
</Transforms>
<DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
<DigestValue>REcwU+gablenV+bEsnzWgvrkthDMvbku2wL49GKLsDU=</DigestValue>
</Reference>
```

Currently, both of your references refer the same enveloping content, while having different digests. That obviously fails the validation.

You may try to fix the reference to see if it helps you to resolve the issue.

Comment: Thanks. I solved it already. I got rid of Xpath and used only C14N and enveloped transform and fixed the references. The next thing was to add the ds: prefix since it's set mandatory for this API(..) and make sure to not recompute digest of xades part while adding prefix.

Comment: The introduction of ds: prefix will in fact have an impact on the digest computation even after the canonicalization. So you shall add all the required prefixes before you apply the canonicalization and compute digests for references and/or SignatureValue,